# Call Microservice from Another Service with OAuth2 or OIDC

Tags: .net-core, oauth-2.0, microservices, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have two services developed with .net core 3.1 that use IdentityServer4 for Authentication.
I have an Angular client Application that call the first service AuthorizationService that also calls another service MembershipService.

I want Authorization Service to call MembershipService using its client ID and Secret rather than using the token provided by the user as I dont want the user to be able to access MembershipService but only Authorization Service.
How to configure one service as a client for another service.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [ExtensionGrant](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html?highlight=delegation#extension-grants) validator in your ID4 token provider service. Once you provide support for the extension grant type you can create a separate ID4 client for `AuthorizationService` along with its own GrantType and ClientScope.

Whenever `AuthorizationService` wants to communicate with `MembershipService` then get delegated token from ID4 and pass that newly received token with an HTTP request.

Client Config:

- ClientId: `authServiceClient`
- GrantType: `delegation`
- ClientScope: `authService_Scope`

I hope this answer will help you, Happy coding!